# Problems with googlecharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, charts

I am with following problem, when I initialize my site I can see the chart, but when I click to go to page he of the problem and not the shows. The site was programmed in Ajax, therefore I would give only a div. The following code is in one of these pages that I draw with Ajax. This feature page I call the dashboard:

```
google.charts.load("current", {packages: ["corechart"]});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Usado', 'Liberado'],
        ['Usado', <?php echo $tamanho->USADO ?>],
        ['Liberado', <?php echo $tamanho->LIBERADO ?>]
    ]);

var options = {
    title: 'Banco de dados',
    is3D: true,
};

var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart_3d'));
chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

My index I include myself the following directory web:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
```

When I open the console of chrome, I am informed of the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: google.charts.load() cannot be called more than once with version 44 or earlier.
```

Searching the Internet not found nothing concrete, however I noticed that is something related to quantity of calls made. Not believed for obvious reasons of non-operation of the amendments. Someone knows how to fix the problem ?

Comment: hi, trying to understand... when do you have problems with your chart?

Comment: @rick The problem occurs when i am in a different page any and I click to go to the dashboard. Os of the problem when it is in this situation, if I reload the page, it appears normally.

Answer (score 0):

I know that it is too late, but in case you still didn't found a solution, you can try this:

```
google.charts.load('45', {packages: ['corechart']});
```

write "45" instead of "current", because "current" is still version "44".
This worked for me